# Does WebSockets have a throughput limit?

Tags: html, websocket

Just wondering - does WebSockets have a limit on how fast you can pipe data through? Can you transfer more data with a pool of sockets vs. a single socket, or is the limit just the speed of the client's internet connection regardless?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An exact answer probably depends on which WebSocket implimentations you are using, but in general there shouldn't be any WebSocket specific bandwidth limitations. There is some minor overhead with respect to the framing, UTF8 validation (text messages only), and masking (client to server messages only) that is not present in a raw binary TCP connection. With sufficient CPU these should scale up to the available bandwidth.

Comment: I caught up with a Firefox senior engineer recently and he confirmed that the window size does scale up to maximise the available bandwidth. Thanks for your response!